# Controlling uninitialized memory with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: linux, memory, c

I was trying to control uninitialized memory as given in [this blog post](http://vulnfactory.org/blog/2010/04/08/controlling-uninitialized-memory-with-ld_preload/).
It says uninitialized memory could be initialized using `LD_PRELOAD`.

example:

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=`perl -e 'print "A"x10000'`
```

and then running a test program.

> LD_PRELOAD are actually loaded at runtime, ld.so copies the name of each library onto the stack prior to executing the program, and doesn’t clean up after itself. By specifying a very long LD_PRELOAD variable and executing a binary, a portion of the stack will be overwritten with part of the LD_PRELOAD variable during linking, and it will stay that way once execution of the program begins, even on setuid binaries, where the library itself is not loaded.

I can get the results in `3.0.0-12-generic`-based Ubuntu but not in `4.6.0-kali1-686-pae`.

Are there any security implementations newly introduced?

**Unobserved results 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae.**

[image: 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae.]

Please tell if more info is required for this question ? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `LD_PRELOAD` is meant to work*.  And I'm really struggling to find how it could ever worked.  When I perform the following on the latest linux kernel (4.7), latest `glibc` (2.27) and latest `ld` (binutils 2.27) I get the following:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD='0000000' less pp.c
ERROR: ld.so: object '0000000' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

[4]+  Stopped                 LD_PRELOAD='0000000' less pp.c
```

So yeah, `ld` simply complains that the object (here 0x00000) is not an ELF.   This comes from `elf/rtld.c` in `glibc`, here:

```
static unsigned int
do_preload (const char *fname, struct link_map *main_map, const char *where)
{
  const char *objname;
  const char *err_str = NULL;
  struct map_args args;
  bool malloced;

  args.str = fname;
  args.loader = main_map;
  args.mode = __RTLD_SECURE;

  unsigned int old_nloaded = GL(dl_ns)[LM_ID_BASE]._ns_nloaded;

  (void) _dl_catch_error (&objname, &err_str, &malloced, map_doit, &args);
  if (__glibc_unlikely (err_str != NULL))
    {
      _dl_error_printf ("\
ERROR: ld.so: object '%s' from %s cannot be preloaded (%s): ignored.\n",
            fname, where, err_str);
      /* No need to call free, this is still before
     the libc's malloc is used.  */
    }
  else if (GL(dl_ns)[LM_ID_BASE]._ns_nloaded != old_nloaded)
    /* It is no duplicate.  */
    return 1;

  /* Nothing loaded.  */
  return 0;
}
```

`do_preload` is called for every object in `LD_PRELOAD` (separated either by space or colon).  Now ubuntu 3.0.0 was released around July 2011, at that time the latest `glibc` was 2.15;  I looked at `do_preload` in `glibc-2.15` and found the exact same code.

Now, maybe the ubuntu guys used an old glibc, say `glibc-2.11` (November 2009, and that's pushing it far).  If you look at that code, you see that `do_preload` is still the same.  That code has been added in 1998 and never changed.

The only thing I can think of are features added by ubuntu at the time (but that's pretty dubious).  It should have nothing to do with the linux kernel since it is the linker's work to add the correct shared objects (Just in case, I went to one of those code indexers for the kernel code and checked all 3.x and 4.x kernels.  And, as expected, LD_PRELOAD is not used anywhere).

---

The only thing I can do is to argue about how `LD_PRELOAD` *should* be used.  And how to achieve a similar effect taking into consideration the above excerpt from `glibc`.  The first option to get that shellcode into memory uses `LD_PRELOAD` properly (but that is very different from what they do in that blog post), the second option uses the environment (which I believe is what they are seeing in the blog post and misunderstanding it as a loaded shared object).

### Option 1: use a real shared object in `LD_PRELOAD`

The current `ld` will check whether the object pointed by `LD_PRELOAD` is an ELF, i.e. that it starts with `\x7fELF`.  A better way to achieve the loading of specific code into a program's memory is to create an ELF yourself and then point to it with `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
$ perl -e 'print "int yay(void){char *x=\"" . "A"x10000 . "\"; return 0;}\n"' > pp.c
$ gcc -o pp.so -fPIC -shared pp.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=./pp.so less pp.c
# And Ctrl+Z to send SIGTSTP
$ jobs -l
[1]+ 15476 Stopped                 LD_PRELOAD=./pp.so less pp.c
$ cat /proc/15476/maps
00400000-00422000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3811056                            /usr/bin/less
00621000-00622000 r--p 00021000 08:03 3811056                            /usr/bin/less
00622000-00626000 rw-p 00022000 08:03 3811056                            /usr/bin/less
00626000-0062a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01336000-01357000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f0328272000-7f0328525000 r--p 00000000 08:03 3845397                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f0328525000-7f032853d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3804385                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.24.so
7f032853d000-7f032873c000 ---p 00018000 08:03 3804385                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.24.so
7f032873c000-7f032873d000 r--p 00017000 08:03 3804385                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.24.so
7f032873d000-7f032873e000 rw-p 00018000 08:03 3804385                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.24.so
7f032873e000-7f0328742000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0328742000-7f03288d7000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3804421                    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
7f03288d7000-7f0328ad6000 ---p 00195000 08:03 3804421                    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
7f0328ad6000-7f0328ada000 r--p 00194000 08:03 3804421                    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
7f0328ada000-7f0328adc000 rw-p 00198000 08:03 3804421                    /usr/lib/libc-2.24.so
7f0328adc000-7f0328ae0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0328ae0000-7f0328b52000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3811050                    /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.7
7f0328b52000-7f0328d51000 ---p 00072000 08:03 3811050                    /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.7
7f0328d51000-7f0328d52000 r--p 00071000 08:03 3811050                    /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.7
7f0328d52000-7f0328d53000 rw-p 00072000 08:03 3811050                    /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.7
7f0328d53000-7f0328dba000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3804648                    /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.0
7f0328dba000-7f0328fba000 ---p 00067000 08:03 3804648                    /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.0
7f0328fba000-7f0328fbe000 r--p 00067000 08:03 3804648                    /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.0
7f0328fbe000-7f0328fc0000 rw-p 0006b000 08:03 3804648                    /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.0
7f0328fc0000-7f0328fc3000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f0328fc3000-7f03291c2000 ---p 00003000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f03291c2000-7f03291c3000 r--p 00002000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f03291c3000-7f03291c4000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f03291c4000-7f03291e7000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3804420                    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
7f03293b0000-7f03293b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f03293e4000-7f03293e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f03293e6000-7f03293e7000 r--p 00022000 08:03 3804420                    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
7f03293e7000-7f03293e8000 rw-p 00023000 08:03 3804420                    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
7f03293e8000-7f03293e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff77a97000-7fff77ab8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff77bb5000-7fff77bb7000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff77bb7000-7fff77bb9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

The important bit that `/proc/<PID>/maps` tells us is the memory location of the object, the "AAAAA...AAAA" string should be somewhere in there:

```
7f0328fc0000-7f0328fc3000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f0328fc3000-7f03291c2000 ---p 00003000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f03291c2000-7f03291c3000 r--p 00002000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
7f03291c3000-7f03291c4000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 3801272                    /home/grochmal/tmp/pp.so
```

We can now use GDB to check it (note that I'm again using the PID I got from `jobs -l`):

```
# gdb -q -p 15476
...
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for ./pp.so
...
```

That line appears if GDB is running in a different working directory than the process was started.  But that's fine, we are after memory not symbols.

```
(gdb) p 0x7f03291c4000 - 0x7f0328fc0000
$1 = 2113536
(gdb) x/2113536x 0x7f0328fc0000
```

(I took the numbers from the maps and used GDB as a calculator)

That will print a lot of stuff (all memory of the shared object we created, including bits added by ELF and PIC), but will show all the "A"s we are after:

```
...
0x7f0328fc2ae0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2af0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b00: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b10: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b20: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b30: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b40: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b50: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b60: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b70: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b80: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2b90: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7f0328fc2ba0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
...
```

### Option 2: use the environment

Now, this does not need the environment variable to be called `LD_PRELOAD`.  The variable can be anything.  Let's start by adding our shellcode ("AAAA...") to `LD_PRELOAD` as they did in the blog post:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=`perl -e 'print "A"x30'` less pp.c
ERROR: ld.so: object 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

[1]+  Stopped                 LD_PRELOAD=`perl -e 'print "A"x30'` less pp.c
$ jobs -l
[1]+  1566 Stopped                 LD_PRELOAD=`perl -e 'print "A"x30'` less pp.c
```

We got the warning alright, we will ignore it and attach GDB:

```
# gdb -q -p 1566
(gdb) info variable environ
All variables matching regular expression "environ":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00007fb7bd5babd8  last_environ
0x00007fb7bd5bbf18  __environ
0x00007fb7bd5bbf18  _environ
0x00007fb7bd5bbf18  environ
0x00007fb7bdcc30c0  __environ
0x00007fb7bdcc30c0  _environ
0x00007fb7bdcc30c0  environ
```

And search for the `environ` variable (`man 3 environ`).  We have two of them, that's a peculiarity of kernel 4.  `environ` is a `char**` so lets look at finding those strings:

```
(gdb) x/3gx 0x00007fb7bd5bbf18
0x7fb7bd5bbf18 <environ>:   0x00007ffd1c3884a0  0x0000000000000000
0x7fb7bd5bbf28 <buflen.8581>:   0x0000000000000000
(gdb) x/3gx 0x00007fb7bdcc30c0
0x7fb7bdcc30c0 <environ>:   0x00007ffd1c3884a0  0x0000000000000000
0x7fb7bdcc30d0: 0x0000000000000000
```

Both `environ` symbols are pointing to the same place in memory (namely `0x00007ffd1c3884a0`).  Let's see what is in there:

```
(gdb) x/20gx 0x00007ffd1c3884a0
0x7ffd1c3884a0: 0x00007ffd1c388ba3  0x00007ffd1c388bcd
0x7ffd1c3884b0: 0x00007ffd1c388bd8  0x00007ffd1c388bea
0x7ffd1c3884c0: 0x00007ffd1c388c05  0x00007ffd1c388c15
0x7ffd1c3884d0: 0x00007ffd1c388c27  0x00007ffd1c388c4c
0x7ffd1c3884e0: 0x00007ffd1c388c6c  0x00007ffd1c388c8b
0x7ffd1c3884f0: 0x00007ffd1c388c99  0x00007ffd1c388cd1
0x7ffd1c388500: 0x00007ffd1c388cfa  0x00007ffd1c388d49
0x7ffd1c388510: 0x00007ffd1c388d67  0x00007ffd1c388e01
0x7ffd1c388520: 0x00007ffd1c388e10  0x00007ffd1c388e27
0x7ffd1c388530: 0x00007ffd1c388e38  0x00007ffd1c388ebd
```

I bet those are strings, let's see:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007ffd1c388ba3
0x7ffd1c388ba3: "LD_PRELOAD=", 'A' <repeats 30 times>
(gdb) x/s 0x00007ffd1c388bcd
0x7ffd1c388bcd: "XDG_VTNR=2"
(gdb) x/s 0x00007ffd1c388bd8
0x7ffd1c388bd8: "XDG_SESSION_ID=c1"
```

Correct, strings.  And we also found our shellcode.  We only need to print it in a different way to get the 0x41s:

```
(gdb) x/20wx 0x00007ffd1c388ba3
0x7ffd1c388ba3: 0x505f444c  0x4f4c4552  0x413d4441  0x41414141
0x7ffd1c388bb3: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7ffd1c388bc3: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x44580041  0x54565f47
0x7ffd1c388bd3: 0x323d524e  0x47445800  0x5345535f  0x4e4f4953
0x7ffd1c388be3: 0x3d44495f  0x54003163  0x3d4d5245  0x74767872
```

**Important note**: This has nothing to do with `LD_PRELOAD`!  The program start as:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=`perl -e 'print "A"x30'` less pp.c
```

Could be pretty much done with:

```
$ YAY=`perl -e 'print "A"x30'` less pp.c
```

And we would achieve the same result.  But I strongly believe this is what they're actually seeing in that blog post.

---

<sub>* I do not have anything running Ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic, but I suppose that its `ld` was more permissive and allowed non ELF objects to be loaded.  I'm confident that my Arch 4.7 simply rejects the object in `LD_PRELOAD` if it is not a proper ELF and has no PIC indicators.</sub>

Comment: Hi.beautiful answer. That means from your case. When this dynamic library will be loaded.
char *x points to the address which has "AAAAAAA..". .. Dump of that location gives the output :-). "So we are able to initialize uninitialized memory". This string should be string literal ,i.e code section of the dynamic library.---> is this assumption correct ?

Comment: @souravpunoriyar - Yesterday I was curious and did some analysis on how it could have worked for you in ubuntu 3.0.0.  But it was not very fruitful, I have added it to the answer anyway.  But yeah, dumping the "AAA..." into the stack adds the string to the `.rodata` section (which should be fine against something like NX in most cases, since it will prevent only writable `.data` from executing).  Another option would be to manually edit the `.fini` section or the end of the `.text` section inside `pp.so`, where the `yay` function is located.

Comment: I exported LD_PRELOAD with pp.so and then executed another program. A/c ldd command it has to load pp.so at runtime.I am not calling yay(). Will it still load , will the code yay() still exist in memory ?... even if i am not using yay. I guess it wont be present.
i was trying nebula level11 question. When i came across all these.

Comment: I am trying to find out through dumps..but not getting it. :-(

Comment: you can take a look
http://cybergibbons.com/security-2/nebula-walkthrough/nebula-exploit-exercises-walkthrough-level11/

Comment: @souravpunoriyar - It will load, always.  That is the nature of shared libraries.  With static libraries you could select only the symbols an executable actually called, this is not possbile with shared libraries because you may be sharing the library among executables.  So, when a shared library is loaded, all symbols must be there.  But do check `/proc/<PID>/maps`, looking through the entire memory of a process is a daunting task, but the `maps` give you the memory locations where the shared library should be (although that still may be several pages of output in GDB).

Comment: its glibc 2.13.. thanks for directing towards do_preload...

Comment: You are correct . do_preload is same as you mentioned.
I tried everything again
using export LD_PRELOAD=`python -c 'print "A"*1000'`
which made LD_PRELOAD=AAAAAAAAA....... 
Hence when ld loads and compare the strings .. it will definitely fail, but the memory in which the string name was taken is not reinitialized to null.I tested this in libc-2.13.. Please give your opinion ?

Comment: @souravpunoriyar - Hahahahahaha.... yes, of course.  They're taking it from `environ` (the environment within process memory).  And it makes some sense in being different between kernel/machines because kernel 4 has an extra environ.  Let me update the answer with that.

Comment: @souravpunoriyar - updated with the `environ` things, I strongly believe that the guys simply found the shellcode in the environment in memory and assumed that can be done with LD_PRELOAD only.  Nope, that works with any environment variable.

Comment: Awsm working with you...Let me understand the answer !!! :-)